# How to validate WebRTC connection signals when peers can't trust each other?

Tags: webrtc

I am building a WebRTC app where two users are selected at random and then connect to each other to chat. Both clients keep an open WebSocket connection and I am planning to use this to exchange their offers/answers to signal a connection. The case I am trying to account for is when there is a peer that intentionally sends bad configuration information, and also when the peer might spontaneously disconnect in the middle of the signaling exchange.

My solution to the first case is have the server keep state of the exchange, so when the connection is first established I would expect that user A provide an offer and user B have an answer. Is this appropriate? or should this be implemented exclusively client side?

My solution to the second problem feels to me like a hack. What I am trying to do is notify the user that a match has been made and then the user will set a timeout say 20 seconds, if a connection hasn't been made in that amount of time then it should move on...

Are these appropriate solutions? How do you reliably establish a WebRTC when either peer can't be trusted? Should the signaling server be concerned with the state of the exchange?

Comment: I don't get what you're worrying about. Even bad actors want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're more concerned about call set up errors rather than being able to trust the identity of the remote peer. They are two very different problems.

Assuming it is the call set up errors you are concerned about you shouldn't be trying to avoid them you should be trying to make sure your application can handle them. Network connection issues are something that will always crop up and need to be handled.

Setting a timer for the establishment of a WebRTC call to complete is a logical solution. Displaying a warning to the user that the time limit is approaching also seems like a good idea. SIP is a signalling protocol and it has a defined timeout for the completion of a transaction and if it doesn't complete within that time it will generate an error response. You could use the same approach.